# Read data from azure blob storage and create chunks of it and Upload it as separate blob files

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to read csv file of millions record trhough readableStream from azure blob storage and creating chunks out of it (10k/20k each) and wants to upload it back to the azure blob storage as separate file.

The current approach I have used is, I read the data as a stream and create local chunks of it on my system and then upload the file one by one on the storage account.

Is there any way I can create and directly write it on the blob storage object.

I have tried the following

```
import csvParser from "csv-parser";

let newchunk: boolean = true, currentChunk: number =0, currentIndex: number = 1, chunkWriteStream: any;
const writeStream = azureBlobObject.download(0).readableStreamBody; 
writeStream.pipe(csvParser())
                .on('data', (data: any) => {

                    if(newchunk) {
                        newchunk = false;
                        const newContainerClient = this.AzureBlobConInstance.getContainerClient(container);
                        const newBlobClient: BlockBlobClient = newContainerClient.getBlockBlobClient(`file${currentChunk}`);
                        chunkWriteStream = (newBlobClient.getAppendBlobClient() as any).getBlobAppendStream()//fs.createWriteStream(name, { flags: "a" });
                        chunkWriteStream.write(`${Object.keys(data).join(",")}\n`);
                    }

                    chunkWriteStream.write(`${Object.values(data).join(",")}\n`);

                    if (currentIndex >= chunkSize) {
                        newchunk = true;
                        currentChunk++;
                        currentIndex = 1;
                    } else {
                        currentIndex++;
                    }
                })
```

Comment: Why not just copy the blob?

Comment: I am creating chunks out of the main file which I want for further processing.

Comment: You mean read chunk from source blob, process it and then upload the processed chunk as a separate blob?

Comment: yes, exactly. I have 1lakh records and I create separate blob for every 10k records. I want to create this blob directly on the azure blob while reading.

Comment: Yes, you can directly write the chunks to Azure Blob Storage without saving them locally first. To do so, you can use the BlockBlobClient class provided by the Azure Blob Storage SDK.

Comment: @Sourav Can you please help about which function I should use and how can I actually implement this, thanks in advance.